# How do I get bootstrap rows to work in Angular2 RC6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

When upgrading my app from RC5 to RC6 I started to get this error:

```
zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'row' is not a known element:
1. If 'row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'row' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div *ngIf="!selectedAsset">
        [ERROR ->]<row>
          <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>
```

The error is referencing a standard bootstrap row element that I've never had a problem with in the past. What do I need to do for bootstrap elements to work again in RC6?

NOTE: I've now updated the app to the Angular2.0.0 Release. Still having the same issues.

Comment: It seems like #2 is your guideline?

Comment: I agree, however there is nothing I can find that describes how to add to the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, and I cant imagine doing this for every single bootstrap html element. (Especially when none of this had to be done on RC5 or below.)

Comment: Here's a good thread that addresses the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11251

Comment: Some good comments in there, unfortunately I still dont get how to use the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and the idea about the directive is nice, but I'm not sure where that would go.

Comment: After reading through it myself, I'm a bit confused by the direction the Angular 2 team took on this one.  Here's hoping for an easier flag in RC7?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of your template.

Comment: This didn't make any difference unfortunately. Still get the same errors